# python Name 'package' is not defined error

Tags: python, pip

After installing the `pyautogui` package with pip, I tried using it in the IDLE shell by typing `pyautogui`.

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        pyautogui
NameError: name 'pyautogui' is not defined
```

I have scoured the web but have not been able to identify why IDLE will not recognise that pyautogui is installed.

Please let me know if you need more information to answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing the package first?

Try:

```
import pyautogui
```